# Python: copy a file and rename multiple copies according to csv contents

Tags: python

I have a CSV file containing a list of filenames. I would like to copy an existing file in a directory and then place a copy renamed as one of the filenames in the csv file.

Anyone have some example scripts and/or pointers? My python has become real rusty!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy a file:

```
import os

command = "cp %s %s" % (file_location1, file_location2)  
os.system(command)
```

You can open the file for appending:

```
with open(csv_file_location,'a') as f:
    f.write("%s\n" % file_location2)
```

Comment: So I tried the following, but sometimes it either justs outputs all the row entries in the terminal, and then open up a windows CMD window, or the execution of the script just hangs...   `code  import os
import csv


file_location1 = "blank.mpp"
csv_file_location ="all_projects_2014.csv"

with open(csv_file_location,'r') as f:
    contents = csv.reader(f)
    for row in contents:
        #file_location2 = row + ".mpp"    
        command = "cp %s %s" % (file_location1, row)  
        os.system(command)
        print row `

Comment: Hi, I think this script works, but is there something special I need to do on Windows 8 to allow command to actually copy files? The script simply opens cms windows without copying files.

`import csv



file_location1 = "blank.mpp"


csv_file_location ="all_projects_2014.csv"


with open(csv_file_location,'r') as f:

    contents = csv.reader(f)

    for row in contents:

        second_file = str(row)

        second_file = second_file.translate(None, '[\']')+'.mpp'

        command = "cp %s %s" % (file_location1, second_file)
  
        os.system(command)

        #print command`